# Imacros Clicking On a Background Image Link

Tags: image, background-image, imacros

I am trying to make imacros click on an image but this image which leads to a link is in the background. Since the link is different every time I cannot point to a specific URL so that is not an option.

This is how it looks at the moment, this is working on the normal images
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:IMAGE LINK.png

The website code for the link looks like this:

```
background-image: url("IMAGE LINK.png");

background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 50px 18px;
width: 50px;
height: 19px;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
padding-top: 1px;
margin-left: 7px;
margin-right: 7px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:IMAGE LINK.png
```

You can still use this image command. If image has one part of it that is the same and the rest that is random then replace the random part with * .

edit:
Try to see where image is located inside HTML code. For example if HTML is like this:

Then if you use

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:someclass CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

you can get the screen shot of image.

Comment: The image does not have the random part. The problem is that the image itself is in the background so this macro is unable to access the link that it leads to for some reason (works on the normal links).